# How to connect Config Client to Config server using Eureka server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-boot-configuration

I have Scenario that whenever we use **config server** with **config client** we need to put in bootstrap.yaml. suppose my config server on port **9001** so i need to hardcore this value in properties file that is ***http://localhost:9001:/***

My question is, "it is possible to connect **config client** to **config server** using **eureka server** so that we can remove hardcore properties"

Comment: Yes, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#discovery-first-bootstrap

Comment: I read the documentation do you have any working example please share it. thanks

Comment: a quick google search gives me https://medium.com/@athulravindran/spring-cloud-config-server-discovery-first-vs-config-first-72cc6a56f471

Answer (score 0):

These are properties I used which solved my problem

**Eureka properties**

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
eureka.client.registerWithEureka = true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry = false
server.port = 9050
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9050/eureka/
```

**Config-server properties**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git-url
          username: git-username
          password: git-password
      fail-fast: true
    
server:
  port: 8080
    
eureka:
   client:
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://localhost:9050/eureka
```

**Config-client properties**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: x
  cloud:
    config:
      profile: dev
      fail-fast: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: CONFIGSERVER
      retry:
        initial-interval: 2000
        multiplier: 1.5
        max-interval: 60000
        max-attempts: 100
        
server:
  port: 8081

eureka:
   client:
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://localhost:9050/eureka
      fetch-registry: true
   instance:
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 10
```